# cannot access my own moodle from public ip address

Tags: php, moodle, portforwarding

I have installed Moodle by a LAMP package (Linux, Apache, MySql and php) on Hyper-v and as far as I am inside the LAN everything is working fine and by entering the IP address 192.168.1.83 I can see the main page of Moodle. Since one week ago I have been trying to access the Moodle from outside LAN and checked other similar questions but I was not able and it has made me so disappointed :(

Can anybody share any experience with me, please?

It is good to mention that I have set up port forwarding on the router in order to forward :8010 to 192.168.1.83:80 and :8011 to 192.168.1.83:8080.

I also has changed wwwroot in the file config.php from localhost to http:192.168.1.83

I have inactivated firewall on Linux server which Moodle is located.

When I try :8010 on a browser from outside LAN, the address in the URL gets changed to 192.168.1.83 but there is an error like:

This site cannot be reached.
192.168.1.83 took too long to respond.

Has anybody had such an experience to give me any comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So when you try to access `http://192.168.1.83:8010` , moodle returns an `HTTP 303` which tells the browser that it should redirect another url, which is the one that you configure in moodle's `config.php`.  Because your moodle config has the `wwwroot` configured to be `http://192.168.1.83`, it sends that as the url to which your browser should redirect.  So now your browser tries to load `http://192.168.1.83` but because it does not have access to that LAN address, it is unable to connect.

What I believe would work is if you changed your `wwwroot` in `config.php` to `http://192.168.1.83:8010`.